# How to upload a large data set to a list in Python

Tags: python, database

I'm trying to make word puzzles like the NYT Spelling Bee (there are 6 letters arranged around one center letter, you must spell as many words as you can with only those 7 letters, each word must include the center letter at least once and be at least 3 letters long). I want to write a Python program that will allow me to find all possible answers by taking a list of all the words in a standard English dictionary then checking if each element meets the criteria of being an answer. The program will then return a list of the possible answers.

I have an outline for the code and I've checked that it works by manually entering a small word bank, but I don't know how to upload data sets into a Python program (or where to download a dictionary data base).

Comment: There are a bunch of public lists you can find via your favorite search engine.

Comment: If you want more specific help, you will need to include the **text** based version of the code you have so far, so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to read text files with Python's `open()` function:

```py
with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line)
```

There's multiple resources for wordlists and off-the-shelf Python libraries that can provide word lists, like https://pypi.org/project/english-words/